# Return the rightmost 1 in the binary representation of a number

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Example: For 1010, you should perform some operations to give 0010 as the output. For 1100, you should give 0100. Similarly for 0001, you should return 0001.

I didnot get this part. how come it returned 2 and 4 for the first two number?

Should it not be 0001? right most bit is one?

Comment: I believe the exercise simply asks you to change all 1-valued bits to 0 except the very first one from right to left. So if you have something like 1110, you should keep the rightmost 1-bit (i.e., the second position from right to left) and change the other two to zero. So the answer in this case would be 0010.

Comment: so if you change all the one except the right most would it not be 1000?

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting what rightmost means. It's the digit on *your* right (i.e., closer to your right hand). So if you have a sequence let's say `'ABCD'`, `D` is the rightmost character and `A` the leftmost.

Comment: Use the statement: x & -x;